# Minimum Words matching with MATCH AGAINST in mysql

Tags: mysql, match-against

I have used MATCH AGAINST query to get result.
I want to result if minimum words match from input string whether I want to match minimum 2 words, 3 or 4

```
SELECT *,
MATCH (`text`) AGAINST ('my work involves for' IN BOOLEAN MODE) `score`
FROM `messages`
ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

So If I want to match minimum 2 words, then I want tonly that result which has minimum 2 words match

```
For ex.
work involves my experience -> 3 words match
How you work ? -> 1 word match
Those times do not work for me -> 2 words match
```

Plese Help.

Comment: Must correct myself, the scre tells you the number of matches. See the duplicate topic.